# iFrame scrollTop on a non-local domain

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$("#topofpage").click(function() { 
    $("#iframe_display").scrollTop();
});
```

This doesn't work, it says 'permission denied'. The URL must reside in the same domain for only `scrollTop` to work?  Why is this? Is there any way around it?

How about using server side code using .load instead or something ?

Comment: This is due to [Cross site script](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) issue.

Comment: but for scrollTop? why? is there a way around it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because you cannot execute scripts on *non-local* domains to prevent the cross site scripting a.k.a *XSS*

have a look at [**same origin policy**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)